# ActiveMQ Artemis How to control the multicast queue name?

Tags: activemq-artemis

When a consumer subscribes to a topic, a multicast queue is automatically created with a system generated name. I'd like to know if it's possible to control this name generation to make it more friendly (like consumer_id + session_id + idx).

I was using the web console to monitor, and with the previous version of ActiveMQ (prior to Artemis) I used to see the consumer names for each subscription to a topic which was very convenient.

What I used to see in the web console with ActiveMQ 5.0:

[image]

What I see now in the console with Artemis:

[image]

Comment: Hi, I'm using hawtio to monitor and with previous version of activemq (prior to Artemis) I used to see the consumer names for each subscription to a topic which was very convenient.

Comment: Hi, actually, I'm using hawtio and not the Artemis console. I'll try to use the Artemis web console instead and see if I get everything I need. Thanks

Comment: The ActiveMQ Artemis web console is based on Hawtio 2. It has special features that would not be available in plain Hawtio. I recommend you use the web console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These UUID named queues are temporary subscriptions that will be deleted as soon as the client disconnects.

The classic way of having named durable subscriptions of the form `clientId.subscriptionName` is to set clientId and subscriptionName properties on your client. Note that durable subscriptions will continue to get messages also when the subscriber disconnects.

With Artemis, you can also use the [fully qualified queue names (FQQN)](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/address-model.html#fully-qualified-queue-names) feature to achieve the same, but with the additional benefit of full control on the durable subscription name:

First, create a multicast address like this:

```xml
<address name="example.foo">
    <multicast>
        <queue name="q1"></queue>
        <queue name="q2"></queue>
    </multicast>
</address>
```

At this point, you can send messages to `example.foo` topic and consume them from `example.foo::q1` and `example.foo::q2` queues (note the `::` separator).

Comment: Ok thanks for your quick answer. This implies a change on the client side, anyway to control it on server side?

Comment: I don't think there is a way of doing this server side.

Answer (score 1):

It appears to me that you're not looking in the right place for consumer information in the ActiveMQ Artemis web console. Currently you're looking in the main navigation tree which shows "major" components like acceptors, addresses, queues, etc. Consumers do not appear here by design. Your screenshot of the ActiveMQ Artemis web console simply shows the multicast queues on an address. In the JMS topic use-case each subscriber gets their own queue typically called a "subscription queue". However, a subscription queue is not the same as a consumer. The consumer consumes *from* the subscription queue. If you want to see the corresponding consumers then you need to open the "Consumers" tab.

For example, here is a screen shot when 3 non-durable JMS subscribers are connected to a JMS topic named `myTopic`:

[image]

As you note, the names of the subscription queues don't really tell you much. However, if you click on the "Consumers" tab you will see a wealth of information, e.g.:

[image]

From the "Consumers" tab you can see where consumers are connecting from, what queue & address they're using, when they were created, their client ID, etc. If there are lots of consumers you can filter them based on, for example, the address or queue they're using.

It's important to note that ActiveMQ Artemis does **not** represent every consumer with an underlying JMX MBean. This is what ActiveMQ 5.x does and this can cause resource utilization problems with a large number of consumers since MBeans are fairly "heavy" objects.

**Note:** These screenshots were taken with the latest release (i.e. 2.16.0) which includes a newer version of the web console than the one you appear to be using in your screenshot.